# Getting wrong text in a label array in c#

Tags: c#, label

I created a control array containing labels, but there are wrongs in the text of the third row in the array, I couldn't find a logical reason for this.
the code is as follow

```
Label[,] array_lbl = new Label[16, 7];


for (int w = 0; w < array_lbl.Length; w++)
    {
        for (int w1 = 0; w1 < 7; w1++)
        {
            var labelToRemove = this.panel1.Controls["lbl" + w1.ToString() + w.ToString()];
            this.panel1.Controls.Remove(labelToRemove);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 7; i1++)
        {
            array_lbl[i, i1] = new Label();
            if (i1 == 0) { array_lbl[i, i1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(123)))), ((int)(((byte)(185)))), ((int)(((byte)(40))))); }
            else { array_lbl[i, i1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(53)))), ((int)(((byte)(86)))), ((int)(((byte)(100))))); }
            if (i1 == 6) { array_lbl[i, i1].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 32); }
            else { array_lbl[i, i1].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(191, 32); }
            array_lbl[i, i1].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(i)));
            array_lbl[i, i1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
            array_lbl[i, i1].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22 + 205 * i1, 60 + i * 46);
            array_lbl[i, i1].Text = "";
            array_lbl[i, i1].TabIndex = 6;
            array_lbl[i, i1].TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            //array_lbl[i, i1].Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            array_lbl[i, i1].Name = "lbl" + i.ToString() + i1.ToString();
            //array_lbl[i, i1].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.lbl_Bant_1_name_Click);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(array_lbl[i, i1]);
            array_lbl[i, i1].Text = array_lbl[i, i1].Name;
        }
    }
```

The result that I got it as following:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the GdiCharSet to symbols:

```
array_lbl[i, i1].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(i)))
```

In the last argument `((byte)(i))` when `i` is 2, it will set the GdiCharSet to symbols. You should just simply set `0` (ANSI) or `1` (DEFAULT).

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.gdicharset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you very much, ı corrected it as you told me and now it is ok, thank you again

Comment: @MemduhCüneyt awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the CharSet of your labels in the third row are set to Symbol (=2).

Just simply use

```
array_lbl[i, i1].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);
```

Comment: thank you very much, ı corrected it as you told me and now it is ok, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.font.gdicharset(v=vs.110).aspx

You set your GdiCharSet to "2" in your third row!

Changing:

```
new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(i)));
```

to

```
new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
```

will probably solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, ı corrected it as you told me and now it is ok, thank you again